# Receiving a 2-D list as request parameters in Python Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am attempting to receive a 2-D list in my flask application. The json object sent is as follows:

```
function someFunction() {
  var two_d_arr = [[a,1],[b,2],[c,3]];
  var data = {
    'arr' : two_d_arr
  };

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:5025/',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: data,
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
  });
}
```

I have tried various times to retrieve these tuples as a list and am failing. The way I would want to see them is a list as follows:

```
lst = [[a,1],[b,2],[c,3]]
```

When I print `request.data` I get the following output (formatted for easy reading):

```
ImmutableMultiDict([(
  'callback', u'jQuery1113017347401613369584_1450454196704'), 
  ('liveCells[2][]', u'c'), ('liveCells[2][]', u'3'), 
  ('liveCells[1][]', u'b'), ('liveCells[1][]', u'2'), 
  ('liveCells[0][]', u'a'), ('liveCells[0][]', u'1')
])
```

I have tried various ways to extract just the list (`request.form.getlist`, `request.args.getList`) etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are not encoding the request to JSON. You are only specifying what you expect to *receive* from the server (because you expect JSONP jQuery is including a `callback` parameter).

Encode to JSON on the client side:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:5025/',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

I omitted the `dataType` argument, only set one if jQuery can't autodetect the response type.

On the server side, read the response with `request.get_json()`.